# SlideToggle issues when clicking other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple accordion which is using `slideToggle`, which shows/hide content, based on clicking a link (trigger). The code I'm using works, but can't seem to get it to function properly (or at least the way I want), when you click on another element. For instance, if I click and open `content-a`, and then click `content-b`, I want `content-a` to close and return back to normal (remove active classes) and so forth. The `active` classes is still on the last clicked element. It doesn't toggle.

Not strong in jQuery, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$('.hidden-content').hide();
$('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).find('.arrow').toggleClass('arrow-down arrow-up').siblings().removeClass('arrow-up');
  $('.hidden-content').stop(true).slideUp(300);
  $(this).next('.hidden-content').stop(true).slideToggle(300);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="trigger"><span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>trigger</div>
  <div class="hidden-content">hidden-content</div>

  <div class="trigger"><span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>trigger</div>
  <div class="hidden-content">hidden-content</div>

  <div class="trigger"><span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>trigger</div>
  <div class="hidden-content">hidden-content</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, what exactly isn't working? Seems fine to me.

Comment: An `active` class gets added and doesn't get removed when clicking on the second trigger. So both have active classes.

Comment: Doesn't do that for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/frLvteje/**

Comment: That's odd. Let me take a look again. I may have missed something.

Comment: @adeneo I've updated the code, I was missing the up/down arrows. I think that may be causing the problem.

Comment: Have to admit I don't see the problem either... The `active` classes seem to toggle just fine, so that's no problem anymore (unless I'm missing something). So what **exactly** is the problem you want us to help you with right now, please describe it at clearly as possible. And please do that by updating your question, not just in a commnet, everyone who reads the question must have the right information without having to go through the comments